# Regex - Match different lengths conditioned on look behinds (Python re)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a bunch of websites but want to keep the top level domain (e.g. gov)/ more site components if they are not .com/ .co/ .it, etc.

examples of target matches

1. `www.example.com` -> `example`
2. `www.example.co.uk` -> `example`
3. `abbonamenti.corriere.it` -> `abbonamenti.corriere`
4. `www.example.gov.uk` -> `example.gov`

I tried using this pattern
`re.match(r'^[WWW]*\.*(.*)(?!\.\bCO\b|\bIT\b|\bC\b|\bNET\b|\bORG\b|\bDE\b|\bEU\b).*',"WWW.EXAMPLE.CO.UK").group(1)`
but I get `EXAMPLE.CO` instead.

Is there a way to impose a sort of "condition" on regex, like match different things depending on the negative lookbehind? New to regex so thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in python and grab capture group #1:

```sh
(?i)^(?:www\.)?(.+?)(?:\.co)?\.[a-z]{2,3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvl1YR/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?i)`: Enable ignore case mode
- `^`: Start
- `(?:www\.)?`: Match an optional `www.`
- `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any characters in capture group #1
- `(?:\.co)?`: Match an optional `.co`
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`: Match 2 or 3 letters before end
- `$`: End

Comment: Thank you for this! But it doesn't extract what I want for example 2 - I want to get `example` from `www.example.co.uk` but your regex will give me `example.co`

Comment: ok can you try: `^(?:www\.)?(.+?)(?:\.co)?\.[a-zA-Z\d]{2,3}$`

Comment: works magic!! I modified a little to `^(?:WWW\.)?(.+?)(?:\.CO)?(\.[a-zA-Z\d]{2,3})*$`, for cases like `WWW.ABBONAMENTI.CORRIE` which I didn't put in the question. Thanks!!